# In a BigQuery dataset, how do I change zeroes to null values?

Tags: bigquery

I need to clean a database by changing zeros to null values before looking for trends.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UPDATE operation:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement

Add a WHERE clause to only affect rows where the value is zero.